# Qt - problems with Qt SLOTs

Tags: c++, qt, slot

I'm trying to learn Qt, and I have a problem with SLOT

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QObject::connect(ui.Button_Quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit())); // WORK

    QObject::connect(ui.AddEmployee, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changeText())); // DOESN'T WORK


}

void MainWindow::changeText()
{

    ui.Button_Quit->setText("TEST");

}
```

Why doesn't the 2nd slot work? Sorry for this newbie question, but I have trouble understanding the logic of this library. :-)

Comment: Use the new pointer-to-member-function connect style/syntax. It's checked at compile time. The old `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros are only run-time checked and *you* have to check if they fail rather than the compiler. Avoiding the macros also results in faster code and you can avoid `Q_OBJECT` code bloat in many cases + other advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the comment (Jesper Juhl), the macros work at runtime by resolving into strings.

You can use any one of the below ways (pass the address of the functions)

```
 //THIS WAY, YOU NEED AN ADDITIONAL FUNCTION buttonClicked
 connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::buttonClicked);
```

Using Lambdas:

```
 //THIS WAY, YOU DO NOT REQUIRE AN ADDITIONAL FUNCTION.
 connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked,[=]() { ui->pushButton->setText("TEST"); });
```

Comment: Your examples would be better if they actually used the types that OP use. Also, your lambda example really should use the form that takes a guard destination object (IMHO) - using a guard object will break the connection when the guard gets deleted so you don't call into the lambda when the world has disappeared beneath it. The un-guarded form should rarely (if ever) be used .

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I have understand now :)